# Trying to make a sum of elements in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on a dataframe that looks like that :

| Type 1 | Type 2 | mode | date | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 | 02/01/22 | 32 |
| A | B | 1 | 02/01/22 | 12 |
| A | B | 2 | 02/01/22 | 12 |
| C | B | 2 | 03/01/22 | 7 |

and I want to have the sum for 'one' type 1,

if I make : df.groupby(['date','Type 1'])['volume'].transform('sum') I get the wrong results as for the same type 1 I get 24 for rows 1 and 2.. I want to calculate only one time the number 12 which corresponds to the total volume.

I expect the results to be : 44,44,44,7

Comment: What means `I want to have the sum for 'one' type 1,` ? How looks expected ouput for it?

Comment: I except the output to be here : 44, 44, 44, 7.. Sorry if I don't made it clear enough, just new here

Comment: @Yann Can you please provide a table or code that shows the results you are expecting to see, this can sometimes help any confusion developers have when reading a post?

Answer (score 0):

If need remove duplicated `volume` values before `transform` replace it by `0` in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['sum1'] = (df.assign(new=df['volume'].mask(df.duplicated(['date','Type 1','volume']), 0))
                .groupby(['date','Type 1'])['new']
                .transform('sum'))
print (df)
  Type 1 Type 2  mode      date  volume  sum1
0      A      B     1  02/01/22      32    44
1      A      B     1  02/01/22      12    44
2      A      B     2  02/01/22      12    44
3      C      B     2  03/01/22       7     7
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.assign(new=df['volume'].mask(df.duplicated(['date','Type 1','volume']), 0)))
  Type 1 Type 2  mode      date  volume  new
0      A      B     1  02/01/22      32   32
1      A      B     1  02/01/22      12   12
2      A      B     2  02/01/22      12    0
3      C      B     2  03/01/22       7    7
```